# Efficiently merge 2 large csv files in java by common labels

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, merge, large-files

I need to merge 2 large csv files (approximately 40 million data elements in each so ~500mb) by common row or column labels, which can be specified by the user. For example, if *dataset1.csv* contained:

```
patient_id    x1     x2    x3
pi1           1      2     3
pi3           4      5     6
```

and *dataset2.csv* contained:

```
patient_id    y1    y2    y3
pi0           0     0     0
pi1           11    12    13
pi2           99    98    97
pi3           14    15    16
```

The user could specify to merge these two files by their row labels (the patient ids) and the resulting *output.csv* would be:

```
patient_id    x1   x2   x3   y1    y2   y3
pi1           1    2    3    11    12   13
pi3           4    5    6    14    15   16
```

Since we combine only the information for the patient ids that are common (intersection) to both input files. My strategy to this problem was to create a HashMap, where the row or column labels to be merged (in this case the row labels, which are patient ids) are the keys and the data for the patient id is stored as an ArrayList as the value. I create a HashMap for each input data file and then merge the values based on similar keys. I represent the data as a 2-d ArrayList of type ArrayList> so the merged data also has this type. I then simply iterate through the merged ArrayList> object, which I call a Data type object, and print it to a file. The code is below:

Below is the DataMerge class that is dependent on the below Data class file.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataMerge {


/**Merges two Data objects by a similar label. For example, if two data sets represent
 * different data for the same set of patients, which are represented by their unique patient
 * ID, mergeData will return a data set containing only those patient IDs that are common to both
 * data sets along with the data represented in both data sets. labelInRow1 and labelInRow2 separately 
 * indicate whether the common labels are in separate rows(true) of d1 and d2, respectively, or separate columns otherwise.*/


public static Data mergeData(Data d1, Data d2, boolean labelInRow1, 
        boolean labelInRow2){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mergedData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> d1Map = d1.mapFeatureToData(labelInRow1);
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> d2Map = d2.mapFeatureToData(labelInRow2);
    ArrayList<String> d1Features;
    ArrayList<String> d2Features;

    if (labelInRow1){
        d1Features = d1.getColumnLabels();
    } else {
        d1Features = d1.getRowLabels();
    }
    if (labelInRow2){
        d2Features = d2.getColumnLabels();
    } else {
        d2Features = d2.getRowLabels();
    }
    d1Features.trimToSize();
    d2Features.trimToSize();

    ArrayList<String> mergedFeatures = new ArrayList<String>();
    if ((d1.getLabelLabel() != "") && (d1.getLabelLabel() == "")) {
        mergedFeatures.add(d1.getLabelLabel());
    }
    else if ((d1.getLabelLabel() == "") && (d1.getLabelLabel() != "")) {
        mergedFeatures.add(d2.getLabelLabel());
    } else {
        mergedFeatures.add(d1.getLabelLabel());
    }

    mergedFeatures.addAll(d1Features);
    mergedFeatures.addAll(d2Features);
    mergedFeatures.trimToSize();
    mergedData.add(mergedFeatures);

    for (String key : d1Map.keySet()){
        ArrayList<String> curRow = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (d2Map.containsKey(key)){
            curRow.add(key);
            curRow.addAll(d1Map.get(key));
            curRow.addAll(d2Map.get(key));
            curRow.trimToSize();
            mergedData.add(curRow);
        }
    }
    mergedData.trimToSize();
    Data result = new Data(mergedData, true);
    return result;
}

}
```

Below is the Data type object along with its associated HashMap generating functions with some row and column label extraction methods.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**Represents an unlabeled or labeled data set as a series of nested     ArrayLists, where each nested 
 * ArrayList represents a line of the input data.*/

public class Data {
private ArrayList<String> colLabels = new ArrayList<String>();  //row labels

private ArrayList<String> rowLabels = new ArrayList<String>();  //column labels

private String labelLabel;

private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> unlabeledData; //data without row and column labels



/**Returns an ArrayList of ArrayLists, where each nested ArrayList represents a line
*of the input file.*/
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readFile(String filePath, String fileSep){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    try{
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (filePath));
        String line = input.readLine();
        while (line != null){
            String[] splitLine = line.split(fileSep);
            result.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitLine)));
            line = input.readLine();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    result.trimToSize();;
    return result;
}


/**Returns an ArrayList of ArrayLists, where each nested ArrayList represents a line of the input
 * data but WITHOUT any row or column labels*/


private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> extractLabelsAndData(String filePath, String fileSep){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tempData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    tempData.addAll(readFile(filePath, fileSep));
    tempData.trimToSize();
    this.colLabels.addAll(tempData.remove(0));
    this.labelLabel = this.colLabels.remove(0);
    this.colLabels.trimToSize();
    for (ArrayList<String> line : tempData){
        this.rowLabels.add(line.remove(0));
    }
    this.rowLabels.trimToSize();
    return tempData;
}




/**Returns an ArrayList of ArrayLists, where each nested ArrayList represents a line of the input
 * data but WITHOUT any row or column labels. Does mutate the original data*/
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> extractLabelsAndData (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    for (ArrayList<String> line : data){
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String element : line){
            temp.add(element);
        }
        temp.trimToSize();
        result.add(temp);
    }
    this.colLabels.addAll(result.remove(0));
    this.labelLabel = this.colLabels.remove(0);
    this.colLabels.trimToSize();
    for (ArrayList<String> line : result){
        this.rowLabels.add(line.remove(0));
    }
    this.rowLabels.trimToSize();
    result.trimToSize();
    return result;
}


/**Returns the labelLabel for the data*/
public String getLabelLabel(){
    return this.labelLabel;
}


/**Returns an ArrayList of the labels while maintaining the order
* in which they appear in the data. Row indicates that the desired
* features are all in the same row. Assumed that the labels are in the
* first row of the data. */
public ArrayList<String> getColumnLabels(){
    return this.colLabels;
}


/**Returns an ArrayList of the labels while maintaining the order
* in which they appear in the data. Column indicates that the desired
* features are all in the same column. Assumed that the labels are in the
* first column of the data.*/
public ArrayList<String> getRowLabels(){
    return this.rowLabels;
}


/**Creates a HashMap where a list of feature labels are mapped to the entire data. For example,
 * if a data set contains patient IDs and test results, this function can be used to create
 * a HashMap where the keys are the patient IDs and the values are an ArrayList of the test
 * results. The boolean input isRow, which, when true, designates that the
 * desired keys are listed in the rows or false if they are in the columns.*/
public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mapFeatureToData(boolean isRow){
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> featureMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    if (!isRow){
        for (ArrayList<String> line : this.unlabeledData){
            for (int i = 0; i < this.colLabels.size(); i++){
                if (featureMap.containsKey(this.colLabels.get(i))){
                    featureMap.get(this.colLabels.get(i)).add(line.get(i));
                } else{
                    ArrayList<String> firstValue = new ArrayList<String>();
                    firstValue.add(line.get(i));
                    featureMap.put(this.colLabels.get(i), firstValue);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rowLabels.size(); i++){
            if (!featureMap.containsKey(this.rowLabels.get(i))){
                featureMap.put(this.rowLabels.get(i), this.unlabeledData.get(i));
            } else {
                featureMap.get(this.rowLabels.get(i)).addAll(this.unlabeledData.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    return featureMap;
} 


/**Writes the data to a file in the specified outputPath. sep indicates the data delimiter.
 * labeledOutput indicates whether or not the user wants the data written to a file to be 
 * labeled or unlabeled. If the data was unlabeled to begin with, then labeledOutput 
 * should not be set to true. */
public void writeDataToFile(String outputPath, String sep){
    try {
        PrintStream writer = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (outputPath, true)));
        String sol = this.labelLabel + sep;
        for (int n = 0; n < this.colLabels.size(); n++){
            if (n == this.colLabels.size()-1){
                sol += this.colLabels.get(n) + "\n";
            } else {
                sol += this.colLabels.get(n) + sep;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.unlabeledData.size(); i++){
            ArrayList<String> line = this.unlabeledData.get(i);
            sol += this.rowLabels.get(i) + sep;
            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++){
                if (j == line.size()-1){
                    sol += line.get(j);
                } else {
                    sol += line.get(j) + sep;
                }
            }
            sol += "\n";
        }
        sol = sol.trim();
        writer.print(sol);
        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}


/**Constructor for Data object. filePath specifies the input file directory,
 * fileSep indicates the file separator used in the input file, and hasLabels
 * designates whether the input data has row and column labels. Note that if 
 * hasLabels is set to true, it is assumed that there are BOTH row and column labels*/
public Data(String filePath, String fileSep, boolean hasLabels){
    if (hasLabels){
        this.unlabeledData = extractLabelsAndData(filePath, fileSep);
        this.unlabeledData.trimToSize();
    } else {
        this.unlabeledData = readFile(filePath, fileSep);
        this.unlabeledData.trimToSize();
    }

}


/**Constructor for Data object that accepts nested ArrayLists as inputs*/
public Data (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data, boolean hasLabels){
    if (hasLabels){
        this.unlabeledData = extractLabelsAndData(data);
        this.unlabeledData.trimToSize();
    } else {
        this.unlabeledData = data;
        this.unlabeledData.trimToSize();
    }
}
}
```

The program works for small datasets but it's been 5+ days and the merge still hasn't finished. I'm looking for a more efficient time and memory solution. Someone suggested using byte arrays instead of Strings, which may make it run faster. Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT: I did some digging around in my code and found that reading the input files and merging them takes almost no time (like 20 seconds). Writing the file is the part that takes 5+ days**

Comment: Not what you asked, but if I were merging csv files, Java would be my last solution. :)   I'll leave more knowledgeable folks to answer about java efficiency.

Comment: I completely agree. I can do this easily in R but I'm required to use Java

Comment: Can you use an R library called from Java like JRI?   Or any flavor of SQL called via Hibernate and friends?

Comment: There's always `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` with a call to awk or a perl or ruby script... :)

Comment: Why are you required to use Java?

Comment: Are the IDs sorted? With large amounts of data, I'd avoid trying to fit it all in memory like that. With sorted IDs, you could just keep cursors in each file and and read (and discard rows) until a match is found.

Comment: Have you profiled your existing code to see where the bottleneck is to focus your efficiency attempts?

Comment: Please upload your code that writes the data if that's the problem... I was surprised the merge was taking so long, but I assumed it was that you were putting it all in memory.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thanks for the suggestion. I just thought of doing that and posted the edit.

Comment: @Chill The code is in the Data class and the function is called writeDataToFile. I've read that using BufferedOutputStream should be fast but maybe I'm not doing it right?

Comment: @user3749778 Are you filling up your buffer and deadlocking your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating all your data fields for all your millions of rows of data into one ginormous string then writing that single string.  This is slow death by memory thrashing as you allocate and reallocate extremely large strings, copying them over and over and over for *each field and separator* you're adding to the string.  Around the 3rd or 4th day each string is ... multiple millions of characters long? ... and your poor garbage collector is sweating and taking it out on you.

Don't do that.

Build each line of your output file separately and write it.  Then build the next line.

Furthermore, use the `StringBuilder` class to build the lines, though you'll get such an improvement for the previous step you might not even bother with this.  Though it's the way to do it and you should learn how.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I see what you mean, it's definitely better to write each file rather than storing everything and then writing. I'll make the change and let you know! Thanks for the help

Comment: Not exactly.  As you discovered you can certainly read all your data from both your files and even do the merge.  But _construct one line_ of the output file (data for one `patient_id`) at a time, and write it.  Then throw away that line (happens implicitly of course) and do it again.  And again.  For each `patient_id`.  Then those strings you're building are no more than 100-120 characters each and you don't keep them around longer than it takes to write them.  No memory pressure.

Comment: Sorry! I meant "write each line" rather than "write each file". I definitely understand what your saying. But, for the sake of understanding, why does trying to write the concatenated output String take longer than writing each line? It seems like essentially the same amount of data is being written. Is it simply because sending the big bolus of text chokes up the memory, making the write process have less memory working on it?

Comment: It isn't writing the string, it is _building_ the string.  You are creating a single string that is millions and millions of characters long vs. creating a million strings each only a few characters long ... and discarding each such short (one line) string immediately after writing it.  In the latter case you have in memory your big hashmap of all data - which is apparently around 1gig - + one single 100 character output string.  In the former case you've that that gig of hashmap data plus a multi-gig string plus the _copy_ of that string you're building to add a few chars to the end ...

Comment: plus you may be imagining that you're adding to the string by somehow just adding characters to the end of a buffer.  No!  That's what StringBuilder would do for you - but even then you don't want a single StringBuilder with 1G characters.  What you're doing is taking a long string and a very short string, allocating a _new_ string long enough to hold both, copying everything into the new string, throwing away the old long string and keeping the new long string ... and doing that millions and millions of times as your string grows and grows and grows ...

Comment: P.s. user3749778 ... if this answer helps you ... don't forget to checkmark it to tell others it is the right answer.  (And give me a few points too.)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the great help, makes a lot more sense now. I never knew about this when implementing my program but now that I know, I can avoid this from happening in the future. Appreciate the help!!!